# Disable radio button based on text box value in angular2 using typescript

Tags: angular

### ts

```
objage: number;
underFlag: boolean = false
aboveFlag: boolean = false
ageValidation: any;
num: any;

ageUpdation(PATIENT_AGE) 
{
    alert(JSON.stringify(PATIENT_AGE))
    if (PATIENT_AGE > 18) 
    {
        this.underFlag = false;
        this.aboveFlag = true;
        alert("hi");
    }
    else 
    {
        this.underFlag = true;
        this.aboveFlag = false;
        alert("hi2");
    }
}
```

### html

```
<td colspan="2">
    <input type="number" formControlName="PATIENT_AGE"  placeholder="Enter Age b/w 1 and 100" class="form-control input-sm"  min="1" max="100" [(ngModel)]="PATIENT_AGE" name="PATIENT_AGE" (change)="ageUpdation(PATIENT_AGE)" required/>
    <div id="forAgeDiv"><span id="forAge"></span></div>
</td>

<td>
    <input type="radio" name="PATIENT_TYPE"  formControlName="PATIENT_TYPE"  value="Pediatric" [disabled]="aboveFlag">Pediatric 
</td>

<td>
    <input type="radio" name="PATIENT_TYPE"  formControlName="PATIENT_TYPE"  value="Adolescent" [disabled]="underFlag"> Adolescent
    <br>
</td>
```

How to enable and disable the radio button based on textbox value.
if I entered age is above 18 Adolescent radio button will enable.

else I entered age is below 18 Pediatric radio button will enable.

Comment: Where you stuck around. You should try `[disabled]="!aboveFlag"    and   [disabled]="!underFlag" like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me :

```
<input type="number" formControlName="PATIENT_AGE"  placeholder="Enter Age b/w 1 and 100" class="form-control input-sm"  min="1" max="100" [(ngModel)]="PATIENT_AGE" name="PATIENT_AGE" required/>
 <div id="forAgeDiv"><span id="forAge"></span></div>
</td>

<td>
    <input type="radio" name="PATIENT_TYPE"  formControlName="PATIENT_TYPE"  value="Pediatric" [attr.disabled]="PATIENT_AGE < 18 || null">Pediatric 
</td>

<td>
    <input type="radio" name="PATIENT_TYPE"  formControlName="PATIENT_TYPE"  value="Adolescent" [attr.disabled]="PATIENT_AGE >= 18 || null"> Adolescent
    <br>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... I don't understand why you're using 'formControlName' attribute. This is working for me

```
objage: number;
underFlag: boolean = false
aboveFlag: boolean = false
ageVaildation: any;
num: any;
patient_age: any;

geUpdation(patient_age) {
 alert(JSON.stringify(patient_age))
 if (patient_age > 18) {
    this.underFlag = false;
    this.aboveFlag = true;
    alert("hi");
 }else {
    this.underFlag = true;
    this.aboveFlag = false;
    alert("hi2");
 }
}

<td colspan="2">
 <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Age b/w 1 and 100" class="form-control input-sm"  min="1" max="100" [(ngModel)]="patient_age" name="patient_age" (change)="ageUpdation(patient_age)" required/>
 <div id="forAgeDiv"><span id="forAge"></span></div>
</td>
<td>
 <input type="radio" name="patient_type"   value="Pediatric" [disabled]="aboveFlag">Pediatric 
</td>
<td>
 <input type="radio" name="patient_type"  value="Adolescent" [disabled]="underFlag"> Adolescent
</td>
```

Comment: Without using formcontroler it is already  working for me.I need to use formcontrol to save record in databse.if i use formcontrol it is not working.How to disable with formcontrol